# How to delete rows from table, based on two columns of same table data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with attribute change history, that looks like:

```
| id     | attr     | value  | version |
|--------|----------|--------|---------|
| UUID-1 | name     | chuck  | 1       |
| UUID-1 | password | morris | 1       |
| UUID-1 | name     | chack  | 0       |
| UUID-2 | name     | aron   | 2       |
| UUID-2 | name     | alan   | 1       |
| UUID-2 | name     | agor   | 0       |
```

Now I have to drop old data for every 'id' (rows with MAX(version) should stay), and I want to get:

```
| id     | attr     | value  | version |
|--------|----------|--------|---------|
| UUID-1 | name     | chuck  | 1       |
| UUID-1 | password | morris | 1       |
| UUID-2 | name     | aron   | 2       |
```

So, I've decided that i can obtain this with such construction:

```
DELETE
FROM
    table1 pch
WHERE
    EXISTS (
    SELECT
        id, MAX(version) AS maxVer
    FROM
        table1 pch2
    WHERE
        pch.id = pch2.id AND pch.version != maxVer
    GROUP BY
        id)
```

or something like this, but... oracle sql can't work with aliases in 'where/having' clauses.

any options to do this thing another way?

Comment: UUID-1 has two rows with version = 1. Do you want the max row per ID + ATTR combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a correlated subquery instead of `group by`:

```
DELETE FROM table1 pch
WHERE pch.version < (SELECT MAX(version) AS maxVer
                     FROM table1 pch2
                     WHERE pch.id = pch2.id 
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different variants...
Just one of them:

```sql
delete from t
where 
t.rowid in 
(
select v.rowid 
from (select
       t1.rowid, 
       row_number()over(partition by t1.id,t1.attr order by version desc) rn
      from t t1
    ) v
where rn>1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution.

```sql
delete from history where rowid in
  (select history.rowid from history join
    (select ID, ATTR, max(version) version from history group by ID, ATTR) t
      on history.ID = t.ID and history.ATTR = t.ATTR and history.VERSION <> t.version);
```

First, we find rows with max versions that should not be deleted.
Then we select rowids of those rows that have the same `ID` and `ATTR`, but different `VERSION` (the 'old' rows).
And finally we remove those rows by rowids.

Answer (score 0):

The one I always use is:

```
delete table1 t1
where  t1.rowid in
        ( select lag(rowid) over (partition by id, attr order by version)
          from   table1 );
```

This deletes every previous row in order of version, partitioned by ID and ATTR.

UUID-1 has two rows with version = 1. I have retained the max row per ID + ATTR combination to match your expected results.